# What are alternatives to GeoEXT?

Tags: jquery, geoext

Is there any alternative to [GeoEXT](http://www.geoext.org/) built with jQuery or other java-script framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://geojquery.org

Paul

Comment: Dead link. Try http://jquerygeo.com/

Answer (score 2):

use

[HERON](http://heron-mc.org/)

It is based on the blend of both openlayers and ExtJs, it is gives the test of ful-fledged rich toolkit for web in the field of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryGeo recommended by Spacedman is in alpha state, as is MapQuery http://mapquery.org/

Most of the OpenLayers community seems to be focusing their efforts on GeoEXT in creating new widgets and portals, however there's no reason not to give either of these open source projects a try and see what we can do to help.

Another alternative is Dojo's great looking map charting components http://dojotoolkit.org/features/graphics-and-charting